# PDFkit ignore footer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have installed the [PDFKit gem](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) within my app and if i call .pdf on any of my urls it generates a pdf version of the page.

```
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware,
    :page_size => 'A4',
    :margin_top => '0.39in',
    :margin_right => '0.39in',
    :margin_bottom => '0.39in',
    :margin_left => '0.39in',:print_media_type => true
```

Is set in my `application.rb` file but i have a fixed footer that is jumping in between elements when the page is rendered in pdf is there a way to exclude it so that it is ignored by PDF kit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried adding css specifically for the print media type and setting the footer to not display? Something like:

```
@media print {  
  #footer {  
        display: none;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: your a freeken legend.